# Can we allow for pasting of images in the "Report this ad" modal?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, images, advertising

When reporting an ad we are served this modal:

[image]

Which requires an image of the ad in question. The image uploader looks similar to the one being used in posts, with one big disadvantage though. It won't let you paste an image directly from the clipboard into the image uploader. **Can this be enabled?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for suggesting this. We think it would be valuable to add, however it would be a bit more complicated than just enabling it, therefore we won't be able to do this in the short term. I have added it to the backlog, so we can prioritize it when there is slightly more bandwidth available.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to this. So status-deferred then?